# Reliable html5 input type handling

Tags: javascript, regex, html, input

I know there is a `pattern` a attribute for html5 input tag, but this help to validate the field *after* the user has entered the value.

The request here is to `prevent` the user to type something wrong, instead of correct it after. I'm not interested to discuss if it's better or not - it's just the request.

I also know I could add an event listener for `keyPress` event and decide which chars accept.

But all the examples I saw are not cross-browser compatible (I'm interested at least in FF, Chrome, in both desktop and mobile versions) and they fails because the user can enter "----" or "....".

What could be a reliable, robust, cross-browser regexp pattern to allow the user to type:

- any number [0..9]
- only one decimal point ('.' or ',' converter to the first one)
- a specified number of decimals (i.e. numbers after the decimal point)
- optional only one sign symbol ('+' or '-') as *first char*
- common text commands: arrow keys, copy/cut/paste, backspace, delete, enter

It's better without the use of `jQuery` - because I should add it only for this goal.

Comment: From a UX experience, it's much better to give instant feedback explaining the error than prohibiting them from typing something incorrect and having them trying to figure out why their character isn't on screen

Comment: I understand but, as I wrote, who designed the UI/UX asked for this behavior...

Comment: As a developer, you should be pushing this back saying this is a usability issue and you are going to create a high bounce rate at that section of the site - I know I would stop using it if it stopped me from typing without any feedback

Comment: Well, it's a bit off-topic, anyway: it's not a "site" but a custom web-application to be used by the employers of the same company. They use 10-years old equipments that have some "features" like this one. The boss wants to maintain the same UX to make the transition "transparent". I'm not saying it's the right approach. If it's technically feasible I cannot pushing back saying "I think different"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The request here is to prevent the user" -- don't do that.

If I am typing my name, but my finger slips when typing the <kbd>i</kbd> and I hit the <kbd>8</kbd> key too... no big deal, I just hit backspace, right?

Well, with your idea, wrong. Your name input would disallow numbers, so the accidental <kbd>8</kbd> wouldn't appear, and the backspace would erase the <kbd>i</kbd> instead.

In your question you appear to be seeking a numeric input (have you considered `<input type="number" />`?) so the finger-slip could apply to the <kbd>*</kbd> key when trying to input a <kbd>9</kbd>. Whatever your input the same idea applies.

Always allow the user to type whatever they want. When they are *done* typing (either `onchange` of the element or `onsubmit` of the form), *then* you tell them "hey, this thing you typed doesn't seem right."

Therefore, the behaviour provided by browsers supporting `input[pattern]` is *correct*, and **should not** be changed.

Comment: I could agree - actually I *do* agree. But you should have quoted the whole sentence: "I'm not interested to discuss if it's better or not - it's just the request.". It's a design constraint and it's not made by me...

Comment: @Mark I know, I saw that too. But in a case like this I feel it's best to put your foot down. Use the exact example I gave if you have to. Explain to whoever imposed this design constraint that it's a really really bad idea. No designer with any level of skill would suggest such a constraint. I seriously believe that, if you implement the requested constraint, you will annoy a lot of users.